# How to use type of a property as type of a declaration?

Tags: typescript

Given this simplified code:

```js
class Finder {
  has(prop: string, value){
    return this[prop].indexOf(value) >= 0;
  }
}

type Str = string;
type Num = number;

class A extends Finder {
  string: Str[];
  constructor(...chars){
    super();
    this.string = chars;
  }
}

class B extends Finder {
  numbers: Num[];
  constructor(...ints){
    super();
    this.numbers = ints;
  }
}

const a = new A('a', 'b', 'c');
a.has('string', 'a'); // ok

const b = new B(1, 2, 3);
b.has('numbers', '1');  // should compile error
```

In the `.has` method, how can I declare the type of `value` as the type of `this[prop]` which is dynamic?

I can declare it as `Str | Num` but The class `Finder` is expected to be extended by many other classes similar to `A` and `B`, each with different custom types. So practically, I can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a template:

```
class Finder<T> {
    has(prop: string, value: T) {
        return this[prop].indexOf(value) >= 0;
    }
}

class A extends Finder<string> {
    string: string[];

    constructor(...chars: string[]) {
        super();

        this.string = chars;
    }
}

class B extends Finder<number> {
    numbers: number[];

    constructor(...ints: number[]) {
        super();

        this.numbers = ints;
    }
}
```